# Loading PDF in webView

Tags: android

I created an App which shows a PDF File from their URL. I am able to show the PDF file in `webview` through this code.

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 //   setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview);

    WebView webView = new WebView(webview.this);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new Callback());
    String pdf = "http://msbte.engg-info.website/sites/default/files/sem%20ii%20sample%20qp/22224-Applied-Mathematics-sample-question-paper.pdf";
    webView.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + pdf);
    setContentView(webView);
}

private class Callback extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(
            WebView view, String url) {
        return (false);
    }
}
```

But I am having problem with the `Open Plugin Button` that shows on the upper right side of the screen. I want to disable that button but how is it possible.

[image: Right Upper Side]

[Zoom in out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDoKN.png)

Comment: what adds that button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You can override this onPageFinished method of WebView. like this
>   below -

```
String url = "javascript:(function() {"+"document.querySelector('[role=\"toolbar\"]').remove();})()"

     @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                yourWebView.loadUrl(url);
            }
```

It will remove that top_right button.

> and to remove zoom -

```
yourWebView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
yourWebView().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
```

Comment: Its working  but how i can remove Zoom in out as shown in image

Comment: Sir please check the image first.

Comment: this answer solves your question ,  right , if it helped , feel free to accept .

Comment: yourWebView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false); answer is not solve my problem. I want to remove **Zoom in Out and Page Number** option i was added another image please check that image.

Comment: try updated answer , you need to add this     yourWebView().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
too

Answer (score 0):

You can use below library but it first download the pdf via url then save locally into your device and after that it will show the pdf in its pdfviewer view.

https://github.com/voghDev/PdfViewPager

Answer (score 0):

Use **Google Docs** Viewer to open your PDF File like below

```
WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
String pdf = "http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf";
webview.loadUrl("http://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=" + pdf);
```